# Build Android APK in Redhat using Gradle in Offline mode

Tags: android, linux, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, offline

I am using Gradle 2.13 and trying to build android apk in readhat and system does not have internet access.
I am trying to build android apk offline. But it is throwing some exception and not able to figure out what went wrong.

Main build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'PROJECT'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         :PROJECT:unspecified
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0 available for offline mode.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.831 secs
```

Version :

```
gradle -version
```

> Gradle 2.13

Is there any tutorial available to build an offline apk in redhat/linux machine?

Edit: Update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the gradle plugin for android 2.13 **doesn't exist**.

The latest stable version is 2.1.0. Use:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}
```

Don't confuse **gradle distribution** and the **android plugin for gradle**.

You can define the gradle distribution used by a project in the file
 `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

For example:

```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, I will try it. 
Will it affect the normal android studio build?
I am checking out the code in Linux environment and making the build.
Am I able to point distributionURL to a local path?

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar Of course you can't change the plugin working offline. You have to connect online at least once.